# Show Emoji Keyboard On Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, emoji

so I am building an Android app.  I have used a custom emojicon pack that comes with emojis that look like the iOS ones.  However, I've noticed that KitKat comes with native emoji support, so I want show that to users instead of my custom window if they have KitKat.  How do I show a certain keyboard window, without changing the imeOptions?

I tried `mEditText.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PICTSYMBOLS))`, but that didn't seem to do the trick

Comment: There is no way to force the soft keyboard to show any screen-  the keyboard is an app in android and it chooses to display what it thinks is a appropriate.  Since there are hundreds of keyboards (and the biggest OEM, Samsung, doesn't even use Google's keyboard anymore) you can't make any assumptions.  There is a way to suggest a keyboard show its numberpad layer, but nothing that hints it should show an emoji layer.  In fact, the keyboard may not have an emoji layer.

Comment: ok I suspected that might be the case.  I guess I will just have my kitkat app use the custom emoji then.  Thanks

Comment: check out this project: https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put this properties in your edittext

```
 android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
 android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

check the android stock sms app source

https://raw.github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/master/res/layout/compose_message_activity.xml

this work with swiftkey and google keyboard

Comment: That's not going to work.  Nothing in here means anything to do with emoticons.  No keyboard is going to see that and assume it needs to show emoticons.

Comment: Please try set this two lines and see how the keyboard show emojis button. It work if you have google keyboard installed. If you want show always keyboard like whatsapp you need code a custom implementation .search for open source messaging apps

Comment: It may work on one specific keyboard, but it won't work on all keyboard, or even commonly across keyboards.  Also, its only the textShortMessage flag that does that, the rest isn't needed.  But the Google default keyboard isn't even the most common keyboard anymore.

Comment: I make it work. The only needed attribute is : `android:inputType="textShortMessage"`. But like you said, the user need to select the native keyboard (Google, Swiftkey) on settings.

Answer (score 0):

find the [EmojiEverywhere](https://github.com/chathudan/EmojiEverywhere) which will help to implement emoji. Emoji in TextView, EditText for Android (like Android KitKat Emoji Keyboard)

[image]

Comment: Great mention, but this code is storing emoticons as images in `/res` folder. It's mean that there are no native way to do it, and you need to apport your emoticon images?

Comment: @IgniteCoders you can delete those, then add the icons