# Android : How to programmatically open the soft keyboard in Emoji View

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, emoji

As I see, a way to show default emojis on android is by using the following on an input text.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textShortMessage"
```

When I search, I can't find a way to do this through Java. What I want to make happen is that when the soft keyboard is open, have the user tab a button to switch between emoji view and normal keyboard view.

**Custom Emoji Keyboard.**

I've already implemented this, but it would be much better to and lighter to use Emojis already on the device for post kik-kat.

**Google does switch between this views.**

On Google Allo, pressing the emoji icon inside the editText switch views.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167428/android-keyboard-with-emoji
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418714/show-emoji-keyboard-on-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 2):

**TextView**

Using TextView's [input type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) does not contain what you want...

**Keyboards**

Seems you can show the user a list of available [keyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036435/switch-android-keyboard-profile-programmatically). (the ones that are available on that device)

And with that, see if it has an [Emoji Key Board](http://mashable.com/2014/06/18/emoji-on-android/#jOF7d4BlEkqb) available. But needs at least Android 4.1 it seems.

**Force Part of Key Board**

[Not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095729/how-to-switch-to-numeric-with-special-characters-keyboard-of-edittext-in-android) as far as I can see. You can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560686/programmatically-hide-disable-emoticons-on-android-soft-keyboard) them, it seems.

*I would love to show how to do this, it looks like a neat thing to be able to do. But my google-fu does not show anything close :(

Comment: If you looked at Google's Allo, how do you think they are doing it? It sure seems like they are not using a custom emoji implementation but the native one.

Comment: Could you provide a link with to Google's Allo where it shows the behaviour you want?

Answer (score 2):

After trying for a while I didn't achieved this goal even [injecting a keyevent](http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.Ui81ddyg2f0).

Looking in Google Allo, that looks as a custom implementation. I have switftkey themed keyboard and on KitKat Moto G (1st gen) it's very remarkeable. I tested also on a Marshmallow Moto G (2nd gen) with native keyboard, but contracted, and you can see that isn't the real soft keyboard :

[image]

I think there is no way to achieve this without a [custom emoji's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts).

Comment: Hey is this still the case? Some years passed