# How to show emoji keyboard programatically android?

Tags: java, android

I have a smiley button, i want to create smiley button than show emoji keyboard on android directly. It's any suggestion to show emoji keyboard in `onClick` event? [here the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNVuB.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : How to programatically open the soft keyboard in Emoji View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013723/android-how-to-programatically-open-the-soft-keyboard-in-emoji-view)

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void chooseKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.showInputMethodPicker();
    }
```

call it and choose keyboard.

Comment: i think it's just show keyboard option, i mean, click the smilley keyboard and show keyboard with emoji directly @SourabhWasnik